# Certificate signing using another certificate

Tags: certificate

I have a certificate with pfx extension which is issued by an application (the cert is self signed).

I have a certificate in the server which is already signed by the CA. If I want to sign the application created certificate using the CA sign certificate, how could I do that?

I'm using a Windows 2012 server.

Comment: Anyone has anything to say?

Comment: Or is there a way I can get a self signed certificate signed by CA to make it valid.

Answer (score 0):

> **If I want to sign the application created certificate using the CA sign certificate, how could I do that?**

It is not so easy... As the certificate is self signed, it is created. **We can not re-sign this by a CA.**

All we could do is to create a certificate request with the same private key and the same subject name, subject alternative name, and extensions (excluding AKI).

**This results in a different certificate with the same cryptographic abilities**. So you can decrypt what has been and sign with the same results as the other certificate. **BUT: it is not the same certificate**.

There are some common ways to identify certificates:

**1. Subject and Issuer**: The subject would be the same, but the issuer is the certificate itself vs. the CA.

**2.  AKI/SKI**: The Subject Key Identifier would be the same as the same private key was used.
The Authority Key Identifier would be different: None (self signed usually does not do this) vs. the CA

**3.  Thumbprint**: The thumbprint would be the same as it is a hash over the public key.

**So will that work for you? I have no idea. The information you gave is just "application running on Windows 2012".** If you provide more information we might be able to help more.

Here is an example on how to extract the private key:

```sh
openssl pkcs12 -in ".\certificate.pfx" -nocerts -nodes -out ".\private.key" -passin "pass:12345678"
```

Here is an example on how to create a certificate signing request to be submitted to the CA with an existing private key:

```sh
openssl req -new -key ".\private.key" -out ".\request.p10"
```